# Simple format statement not working in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Following simple code is not loading in Lisp:

```
(defun helloworld (name)
    format t ("~%Hello from Lisp, ~A!" name )
)
```

I have also tried to put parenthesis around format statement, but still it does not work. The error is:

```
*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: invalid form ("~%Hello from Lisp, ~A!" NAME)
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the wrong use of the parentheses. Try this:

```
(defun helloworld (name)
    (format t "~%Hello from Lisp, ~A!" name))
```

Remeber, you must always use forms, i.e. `(operator arguments)` instead of commands as in other programming languages.

To reduce the number of these errors, you could use a Common-Lisp aware editor, that align the lines according to their syntactic meaning. One of the best editor in this respect is the combination [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) + [SLIME](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), but there are other possibilities.